# MVC4 ajax call and return data properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I invoke an action in a controller using ajax like below.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getUserInfo.json",
            data: "",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.resultInfo.result != "SUCCESS") { alert("error"); return; }
                setUserInfo(data.userInfo);

                //alert(data.resultInfo.result);
                //alert(data.resultInfo.message);

                settingMenu();
                //historyBackProc(); //histroyback catch
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data.resultInfo.message);
            }
});
```

And what it ends up calling is this action.

```
public ActionResult getUserInfo()
        {
            if ( Session["UserInfo"] != null ) {
                ViewData.Add("resultInfo", new resultInfo("SUCCESS"));
                ViewData.Add("UserInfo", Session["UserInfo"]);
                return Json(ViewData);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("index.mon");
            }
        }
```

and back to the ajax success callback, the data isn't what I want it to be.

What I want is,

```
data
 - "resultInfo" : object
 - "UserInfo" : object
```

But it ended up having just objects, not keys.

```
data
 - object[0]
   - Key : "resultInfo"
   - Value : object
 - object[1]
   - Key : "UserInfo"
   - Value : object
```

To achieve this, how to manipulate the return object in the action?
I need to do this to run this web application with the absolutely same javascript in both JAVA and .NET environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `ViewData` when you are returning JSON. You are getting result since  `ViewData` is a dictionary.

Use

```
return Json(new {
    resultInfo = new resultInfo("SUCCESS"),
    UserInfo = Session["UserInfo"]
});
```

instead of

```
ViewData.Add("resultInfo", new resultInfo("SUCCESS"));
ViewData.Add("UserInfo", Session["UserInfo"]);
return Json(ViewData);
```

Comment: That looks like what I'm looking for! but declaring the object like above causes an error, saying " invalid anonymous type member declarator blah..blah..blahh "  missing some brakets there?

Comment: great, working nicely!! two thumbs up! thanks! this is very script-like :D I like it!! thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

```
        Dim data As New SortedDictionary(Of String, String)
        data.add("key","value")
        data.add("key2","value2")
        Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
        Return serializer.Serialize(data)
```